# CSS3 background angled gradient becomes horizontal on wide screens

Tags: google-chrome, css, gradient

I've got an angled CSS gradient at http://jsfiddle.net/jeepstone/GLcRe/

In Firefox this is fine, but in Chrome, when you make the window wider the line becomes horizontal. It's doesn't do this within JSfiddle (!). Any ideas how I can prevent this?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the given problem?

Comment: Sure, this is the (expected) bahaviour: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2374201/normal_width.png This is the wide behaviour: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2374201/wide.png

Comment: Try to disable this line: 
    `background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgb(185,192,0)), color-stop(30%,rgb(185,192,0)), color-stop(30%,rgb(255,255,255)), color-stop(100%,rgb(255,255,255)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like currently there isn't a way to position the linear gradient, so I've reverted to a png for the diagonal line.